# NSMutableArray memory Management when allocated directly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I know that when we add an object **obj** into a NSMutableArray, it takes the co_ownership of that object. So we can release the object **obj** just after adding that into the NSMutableArray. And when we release the NSMutableArray, it also calls the release of all the objects in it. So there is no memory leak and every thing is fine.

My doubt is if do like

```
NSMutableArray myArray = [[NMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:[MyClass alloc] init]];
[myArray release];
```

Will this Cause any memory leak in our program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `autorelease` for your `MyClass`. That should fix any memory leaks

```
NSMutableArray myArray = [[NMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
[myArray release];
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed, it will cause a memory leak.

The offensing line is (I have splitted it for clarity):

```
[myArray addObject:
    [[MyClass alloc] init] // <- An instance is allocated with ownership
]; // <- The array retains the instance
```

At the end, [the retain/release ownership are not balanced](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) and causes the leak.

One solution is to make the allocation before the addition:

```
MyClass *obj = [MyClass alloc] init];
[[myArray addObject:obj];
[obj release];
```